# Accurately detecting a captive portal in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking

I need to reliably detect if a device has full internet access, i.e. that the user is not confined to a captive portal (also called walled garden), i.e. a limited subnet which forces users to submit their credentials on a form in order to get full access.

My app is automating the authentication process, and therefore it is important to know that full internet access is not available before starting the logon activity.

The question is not about how to check that the network interface is up and in a connected state. It is about making sure the device has unrestricted internet access as opposed to a sandboxed intranet segment.

Here is my code to test so far:

```
def get_connection_status(remote_server = "www.google.com"):
    for timeout in [1, 5, 10, 15]:
        try:
            print "Checking internet connection.."
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

            # see if we can resolve the host name -- tells us if there is
            # a DNS listening
            host = socket.gethostbyname(remote_server)

            # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
            # reachable
            s = socket.create_connection((host, 80), 2)
            s.close()

            print 'Internet connected.'
            return "Connected"
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            print "Internet not connected."
    return "Not Connected"
```

Will this accurately return "Not Connected" if the user is within a captive portal? If not, what is a way to improve this method so that it will detect it accurately?

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you expect. Are you trying to detect whether your host is sitting in a fast-food restaurant that makes you go through some advertising before you can access the web? Or are you trying to determine if your host is in a country like China where the internet is partitioned behind a giant firewall?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. An example would be like going to a hotel and connecting to their Wi-Fi, but needing to sign in with credentials before using the full internet. That kind of thing. Closer to your fast food example, I think. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is not specific to Python or any other language.

If one is in `walled_garden`, following factors are standard in most captive portals.

1. You cannot access Internet (implicit, but adding here for the sake of uninitiated)
2. Access to secure web sites (HTTPS) is not allowed. The only exception is the captive portal itself and probably some server(s) allowed by captive portal administrator.

So, one can check if he/she are in a `walled_garden` by performing following tests

1. Check if DNS resolution is working fine. I suggest you use a domain under your control and keep the TTL to a minute or two to ensure the querying servers always come back to your DNS. If DNS test passes, the probability of working Internet connection is very high, though you are still in walled garden.
2. If DNS resolution works, try accessing a secure site (HTTP-SSL) preferably by IP and one of your own servers. If it does not work, continue to next step. You should consider setting a low timeout to ensure you can quickly move to next step.
3. Try accessing one of your own servers using HTTP protocol. If one is in a `walled_garden` he is redirected to the captive portal page. If you compare the page headers received with page headers you have configured on your server, you will know if you are behind `walled_garden`.

Comment: This solution worked well for me. Using the 'Requests' library made it quite easy. Thank you very much.